# "Available 24 hrs a day" vs "Available for 24 hrs a day"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> Food services are available 24 hrs a day.

vs.

> Food services are available **for** 24 hrs a day.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct: it’s perfectly acceptable to drop the “for,” making “24 hrs. a day” an adverbial noun and getting rid of the prepositional phrase. Generally speaking, the shorter sentence is always preferred. (But using the prepositional phrase instead doesn’t sound too unnatural.)

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't agree that the shorter sentence is always preferred. The *clearer* sentence is always preferred, which is *usually* the shorter sentence.